# Talk to distributed components securely

Tags: c#, .net, security, wcf-security

I am designing authentication and security for a distributed application.

The requirements are :-

1) The are are two distributed components A and B
A and B will be always installed in Windows environments. 
A and B can be installed in two different Windows domains which don't trust each other.

2) A and B use WCF for communication.

A and B should be able to authenticate each other and exchange data securely.

What are the ways in which this can be done ?

The possible solutions are :-

a) Implement a CA, issue certificates to A and B. both of these certificates are signed by rootCA. But this solution involves us to implement a CA which is too costly

b) Implement a key generation service on A.

This would look like :-

CreateSymmetricKey(string userName, string password);

A and B would have a self signed certificate.
The data exchanged between A and B would be secured using the self signed certificate.
The authentication is done using userName and password.

This would generate a symmetric key. Both A and B would store this key using local secure storage.

This symmetric key would be used for encryption and authentication for communication between A and B.

Can you suggest of other ways in which this could work ?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

A CA isn't that expensive. Windows Certificate server is built into the server OSes and can be [configured](http://www.leastprivilege.com/HowToBuildADevelopmentTestDemoCA.aspx) to produce an internet hosted CRL, or, at a pinch you can use [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [create a root certificate](http://www.reliablesoftware.com/DasBlog/PermaLink,guid,6507b2c6-473e-4ddc-9e66-8a161e5df6e9.aspx), then generate X509 certificates from that root, and then generate a CRL which you can manually load into the certificate store on the hosting server.

You will need a CRL of either type to make WCF happy.

Comment: By expensive I meant it is expensive to develop and maintain code base for implementing a CA solution custom made for my application.